# protecting /etc/resolv.conf from being overwritten when ppp0 is dialed up

Tags: linux, dhcp, ppp, dial-up

I have an embedded system running a busybox distribution and for some reason i can't seem to find my dhclient.conf (http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dhclient.conf&sektion=5) that would let me "protect" resolv.conf wt but DHCP still works, how could that be? Also, is there another way to protect the nameservers in resolv.conf?

Comment: Belongs to ServerFault or AskUbuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just echoing my nameservers into /etc/resolv.conf after the dial up has been established....

Answer (score 2):

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

will help you ;)

That turns special attributes to protect the file for deletion or modification.

Comment: That gives me this: 
# chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf 
chattr: reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf: Inappropriate ioctl for device my root disk is jffs2 not ext2 - that must be it

Answer (score 0):

Creating a permission of this file.

chmod 0644 /etc/resolv.conf.

Owner can read and write. 6
Group can read.           4
Others can read.          4

Comment: but it belongs to root who is also trriggering the pppd call (frrom an init scrip on bootup...) :( is it feasible to make it chmod 444 ?

Comment: Oh I just see that it doesn't let me set it to anything else, it just stays at 777... hmmm